# Show/hide table columns based on a select value

Tags: jquery, html-table

**Scenario:**
I've got a table where the first column is the "header/legend" and any following column contains the data for a specific year.
Then I have a select with the list of the years to choose from (corresponding to the table's columns).

**Problem:**
When a year is selected I need to display in the table the first column plus the one for the selected year and two more for the two previous years.

*I know about the nth-child method, but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same without looping through the columns
Any ideas?*

**Work in progress:** https://jsfiddle.net/wpnj8917/

```
(still need to show just 3 columns, or less for the last two years in the select)
```

Comment: HTML and current JQuery, please...

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Working from scratch. I know about the nth-child method, but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same without looping through the columns

Comment: ok, got this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wpnj8917/
now the problem is to display just 3 columns (or less for the last two years in the select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hideAll() {
    $('tr td.col').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
}

function showSelected(selected) {
    var first = parseInt(selected);
    var second = first - 1;
    var third = second - 1;
    $('tr td.'+first+', tr td.'+second+', tr td.'+third).each(function(){
        $(this).show();
    });
}
```

here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpnj8917/1/) with the final code